# Intersection between two lists of repetition

Tags: prolog

The list with repetition consists of the elements (element, number_of_occurrences). For two lists of such elements find the intersection.

I wrote the following code

```
min(X,Y,X):-X=<Y.
min(X,Y,Y):-X>Y.

search([X,Y],[[X,W]|_],[X,Z]):-min(Y,W,Z).
search([X,Z],[[_,_]|T],Answer):-search([X,Z],T,Answer).

intersection([],_,[]).
intersection([[H,O]|T],L2,[Z|Temp]):-
         member([H,_],L2),
         search([H,O],L2,Z),
         intersection(T,L2,Temp).
intersection([H|T],L2,Temp):-
         \+member(H,L2),
          intersection(T,L2,Temp).
```

When I test it on this : intersection([[1,2],[2,2],[5,5]] , [[1,1],[2,3],[4,5]],A).
It gives A = [[1, 1], [2, 2]] , A = [[1, 1]] and A = [[2, 2]] 
A = []
I only want the first answer, How can I do it? what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Have a look at `!`. `apropos(!).`

Comment: Even better, try `once(intersection([[1,2],[2,2],[5,5]] , [[1,1],[2,3],[4,5]],A))`.

Comment: @larsmans it works but I don't want this solution :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that using `member/2` followed by a `search/3` creates the subset solutions due to backtracking. The `search/3` predicate will already provide success or failure depending upon membership by its design. So, if you reswizzle your `intersection/3` predicate, you can eliminate the redundancy and enforce the full solution.

You can also eliminate your `min/3` predicate noting that SWI Prolog supports a `min/2`. You would replace `min(Y, W, Z)` with `Z is min(Y, W)`, but just being aware the assumption is that both `Y` and `W` are always instantiated.

```
search([X,Y], [[X,W]|_], [X,Z]) :- Z is min(Y, W).
search([X,Z], [_|T], Answer) :- search([X,Z], T, Answer).

intersection([], _, []).
intersection([[H,O]|T], L2, R) :-
    (  search([H,O], L2, Z)
    -> R = [Z|Temp]
    ;  R = Temp
    ),
    intersection(T, L2, Temp).

?- intersection([[1,2],[2,2],[5,5]], [[1,1],[2,3],[4,5]], A).
A = [[1, 1], [2, 2]].

?-
```